# Add all the same type of objects in an array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array of objects which I am trying to condense in php. This is my array

```
$proposedStudentFeeCollection = [{"id":1,"student_id":"1","feeType_id":"2","proposed_fee":"5000"},
{"id":2,"student_id":"1","feeType_id":"1","proposed_fee":"5000"},
{"id":3,"student_id":"1","feeType_id":"1","proposed_fee":"2000"},
{"id":4,"student_id":"1","feeType_id":"2","proposed_fee":"15000"},
{"id":5,"student_id":"1","feeType_id":"2","proposed_fee":"5000"},
{"id":6,"student_id":"1","feeType_id":"11","proposed_fee":"9000"},
{"id":7,"student_id":"1","feeType_id":"1","proposed_fee":"20000"},
{"id":8,"student_id":"1","feeType_id":"16","proposed_fee":"1000"}]
```

I want to get a "**new**" simplified array which gives me sum of same `feeType_id` like so

```
[{"id":1,"student_id":"1","feetype_id":"1","proposed_fee":"27000"},
{"id":2,"student_id":"1","feetype_id":"2","proposed_fee":"25000"},
{"id":3,"student_id":"1","feetype_id":"11","proposed_fee":"9000"},
{"id":4,"student_id":"1","feetype_id":"16","proposed_fee":"1000"}]
```

I am trying to do it like so

```
$myArray = array();
for($i=0; $i<2; $i++){
    $tempObject = $proposedStudentFeeCollection[$i];
    for($j=count($proposedStudentFeeCollection)-1; $j >= 0; $j--) {
        if($tempObject->feetype_id == $proposedStudentFeeCollection[$j]->feetype_id){
            $tempObject->proposed_fee += $proposedStudentFeeCollection[$j]->proposed_fee;
            unset($proposedStudentFeeCollection[$j]);
        }
    }
    $myArray[] = $tempObject;
}
return $myArray;
```

But I am not getting the answer. What is the correct way?

Comment: Is this the output of a database query? If so, it would be easier to do this in the query.

Comment: Looking at the syntax highlighting here reveals that you have an error in your first code: `"9000}` as well as `"20000}` are missing a closing `"`. (And btw, your second, desired code is missing some too)

Comment: That… is not a PHP object array…

Answer (score 0):

Create an associative array that uses the column that you want to group by as a key. Loop over the original array, and add the row if it doesn't already exist in the result, otherwise just add to the total `proposed_fee`.

```
$totals = [];
foreach ($proposedStudentFeeCollection as $e) {
    $id = $e['feeType_id'];
    if (isset($totals[$id])) {
        $totals[$id]['proposed_fee'] += $e['proposed_fee'];
    } else {
        $totals[$id] = $e;
    }
}
```

Comment: $id = $e['feeType_id']; may not work as $e is a json object and needs to be decoded first

Comment: I don't see any quotes that make it JSON. I think he was just using JSON to illustrate how the data is organized.

Answer (score 0):

A simple foreach is all you need. You have to create an element for each feeType_id and then just add up all fees.

```
$id = 1;
$fees = [];
foreach ($proposedStudentFeeCollection as $data) {
    $feeTypeID = $data->feeType_id;
    if (!isset($fees[$feeTypeID])) {
        $fees[$feeTypeID] = new stdClass;
        $fees[$feeTypeID]->id = $id;
        $fees[$feeTypeID]->proposed_fee = 0;
        $fees[$feeTypeID]->student_id = $data->student_id;
        $fees[$feeTypeID]->feeType_id = $data->feeType_id;
        $id++;
    }

    $fees[$feeTypeID]->proposed_fee += $data->proposed_fee;
}

//$fees = array_values($fees);
```

If you dont want the fee type ids as the array keys, just use `array_values` on `$fees` (uncomment last line).

The output is the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [proposed_fee] => 25000
            [student_id] => 1
            [feeType_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [proposed_fee] => 27000
            [student_id] => 1
            [feeType_id] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [proposed_fee] => 9000
            [student_id] => 1
            [feeType_id] => 11
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [proposed_fee] => 1000
            [student_id] => 1
            [feeType_id] => 16
        )

)
```